# check if a checkbox is checked in angular

Tags: angular, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes, and there is a certain input text that I want to show only near a checkbox that is checked.
In AngularJs it is very very simple. In angular it seems impossible.
I saw this question with many answers, none of them worked!
Can anyone give me a **simple** **working** solution?

Thanks,
Osnat.

Here is my code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let eachService of services; let i = index">
     <td class="service-td" *ngIf="services[i]"><input type="checkbox">
          <span>{{services[i]}}</span>
     </td>
     <input [hidden]="???" type="text" value="wl">
</tr>
```

Comment: please add the sample data for `services`

Comment: services is just an array of strings

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: As I wrote in your answer, it is great for radio buttons but no for checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, here is a working demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-apfdfa :

**component.ts**

```
  selectedValue = '';
  services = ['service 1','service 2', 'service 3'];
  checked($val){
    this.selectedValue = $val;
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let eachService  of services; let i = index">
     <td class="service-td" *ngIf="services[i]">
       <input (change)="checked(eachService)" [checked]="selectedValue == eachService" type="checkbox" [value]="eachService">
          <span>{{eachService}}</span>
     </td>
     <input [hidden]="!(selectedValue === eachService)" type="text" [value]="eachService">
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks! your solution is great for radio button, but I need it for checkbox, more than one item can be checked, and the input text need to disappear when the item is un-checked

Answer (score 0):

it's only use [(ngModel)] and a variable. It you iterate over an array of object, simply add a new propertie "checked" to your object. You can make it "on fly"

Imagine your "services" are an array of object

```
[{name:"Service1",value:"some value"},{name:"service2",value:"some value"}]

<tr *ngFor="let eachService of services; let i = index">
     <td class="service-td">
          <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="eachService.checked">
          <span>{{eachService.name}}</span>
     </td>
     <input [hidden]="!eachService.checked" type="text" [(ngModel)]="eachService.Value">
</tr>
```

Well, but you has not an array of object, you has an array of strings, really two arrays of string (one to show the service, and another one to store the values. Well, create a new array of booleans to show or not the inputs

```
checks:boolean[]=[]
values:string[]=[]
services:string[]=["service1","service2"]

<tr *ngFor="let eachService of services; let i = index">
     <td class="service-td">
          <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checks[i]">
          <span>{{eachService}}</span>
     </td>
     <input [hidden]="!checks[i]" type="text" [(ngModel)]="values[i]">
</tr>
```

NOTE: In this case don't forget, before send the data check if "checks" are true

```
this.values=this.values.filter((x,index)=>this.checks[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple checkbox check and show corresponding div only , there can be various ways you can track.

a. Tracking index and storing in array and showing only checked index.

b. angular already provides @ViewChildren to track elements particularly.

c. You can even create map with key as id and boolean value to show or hide elements.and can toggle using map.

Example using @ViewChildren:-

```
<tr *ngFor="let eachService of services; let i = index">
                <td class="service-td"><input type="checkbox" 
(change)="toggle($event,i)">  
                     <span>{{services[i]}}</span> 
                </td>
                <input  [id]="i" style="display: none;"   type="text" 
 [value]="services[i]" #help>
           </tr>
```

ts file:-

```
@ViewChildren('help') help :any[]; // declare it.


toggle(event,j){
this.help.forEach((ele: ElementRef) => {
  if(ele.nativeElement.id == j && event.target.checked){
    ele.nativeElement.style.display='block';                  
  }else if(ele.nativeElement.id == j && !event.target.checked){
    ele.nativeElement.style.display='none';
  } 

});
}
```

Comment: @ViewChildren('help') help :any[]; doesn';t compile

Comment: what is the error ? make sure you importing @ViewChildren from '@angular/core' and #help has been defined in template

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly do you want, but I think you may need something like this.

`componet.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  services = [{key: "a"},{key: "b"},{key: "c"},{key: "d"}];
}
```

`component.html`

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<tr *ngFor="let eachService of services;">
     <td class="service-td">
       <input [(ngModel)]="eachService.checked" type="checkbox" #p > <span>{{eachService.key}}</span>
       <span *ngIf="eachService.checked">
         <input type="text" placeholder="{{eachService.key}} is selected">
       </span>
     </td>
</tr>
<br>
<br>

{{services | json}}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lr3fat

Comment: It doesn't recognize the "checked" field in the eachService object